# No SaveAs and Report propertiesin the below report

Tags: reporting

[image]

Hi People,

Can anyone help me in knowing why am not getting the save as button and Report properties button in the below report.(shown in the image)

Answer (score 0):

You can't Save As before you Save, nor can you configure the Report Properties before you Save.